# Codeigniter | Save Base64 image to file

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, image-processing, base64

I have created a custom product configurator that saves a canvas element as a base64 encoded image. When I echo the image in the browser as the image src it works fine.

So something like this works:

```
$base64Image = $_POST['dataUrl'];
echo '<img src="'.$base64Image.'" />';
```

My problem is that codeigniter wont add this base64 image src to the session, probably because its too big. I have tried some methods that people have used to write an image to the server and they all throw errors. Does anyone know how I can write this base64 string to an image on the server like 'myimage.png' in the images/custom folder?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you should HTML-escape that dataURI, or you have XSS issues

Comment: Try this: http://j-query.blogspot.in/2011/02/save-base64-encoded-canvas-image-to-png.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also use

```
$decoded=base64_decode($base64Image);
file_put_contents('newImage.JPG',$decoded);
```

Reference Link: http://j-query.blogspot.in/2011/02/save-base64-encoded-canvas-image-to-png.html

Comment: The reference link is EXACTLY what I needed. It's working perfectly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use [tempnam()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) to get a unique file name in a directory writable by the script. You can map a session variable "thisUsersTempFile" to that file name.

Or you can store the association somewhere else if it is not temporary. If you need to clean up the tmp files, you would probably need to do that since I don't think you can hook the session destruction. You could poll for existing sessions and delete the tmpfiles associated with the sessions that were destroyed. You could use a cron job for that.